# iOS access phone settings programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-number

is it possible to access the phone settings of an iOS Device programmatically? I'm currently building an app and there I will provide contact possibillities, for example a direct link for calling (you just push it and then the specific contact number is called).

But I only want to show that possibility, if the user isn't calling with an unknown number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the contacts stored in the phone using the [**Address Book framework**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html). If you're unfamiliar with the framework, I suggest you take a look at this [quick start tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1).

**EDIT** It seems you wish to read the state of the `Show My Caller ID` system setting, however you cannot programmatically access the system settings.

Comment: I think you misunterstood my question: i want to check whether the current device has set his phone number to "hidden" when he is calling somebody -> is he calling with unknown number...

Comment: @ilir-aga You cannot programmatically access the system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ABAddressBook** for getting contact details in your project...

[see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, i descriped my problem wrong: i just wanted to check the value of the system setting "Show My Caller ID" - which is not possible as it seems.